# Array or List inside of a Class to be used in Dictionary C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an existing class named Product

```
public sealed class Product
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double Amount{ get; set; }
}
```

And I use dictionary to populate these fields.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, Product> Products = new Dictionary<int, Product>()
    {
            { 1001, new Product{ Id = 1001, Name = "Product 1", Amount = 50.00 } },
            { 1002, new Product{ Id = 1002, Name = "Product 2", Amount = 30.00 } },
             ...
    }
```

But I have to add a new column named Code and this column may or may not have multiple values.

| ID | Name | Code | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Product 1 | A1001, B1001 | 50.00 |
| 1002 | Product 2 | A1002 | 30.00 |
| 1003 | Product 3 | A1003, B1003 | 100.00 |

I tried creating a separate dictionary for the code and I just used the id as the key.

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, int[]> Codes = new Dictionary<int, int[]>()
        {
            { 1001, new int[] { A1001, B1001 } },
             ...
        }
```

I need to get the product details just by using the **Code**.
Is there any way to utilize the Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the "Product" class; If you use `new int[]` you will get an error while typing the data you specified. You can use `(new int[] { A1001, B1001 }` instead of `new List<string>` or `new string[]`.)

You can add a property named "Code" inside the "Product" class.

You can get the product details as below using just "Code". (Of course, if you have data, you must first return and map with foreach.

```
 Dictionary<string, Product[]> datas = new Dictionary<string, Product[]>()
         {
             { "A1001", new Product[] { .... } },
              ...
         }
```